# Can you use an app as a webpart on a subpage that was create on parent site?

Tags: 2013, app, sub-site

I've created an app wiki library on the parent site, but I would like to be able to use it on a page as a web part on a subsite. Does anyone know how to make the subsite inherit parent apps? The parent is a publishing site and the child is a team collaboration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible, each app is unique within the site. You can use Content Query or Content Search web parts to roll the data down to subsites.